# Can't install any npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I can't install any npm packages. I type in `npm install lodash` and I get:

```
npm WARN webdev@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN webdev@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Blake\Desktop\webdev\node_modules\lodash
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Blake\Desktop\webdev\node_modules\lodash' -> 'C:\Users\Blake\Desktop\webdev\node_modules\.lodash.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-15T21_28_45_978Z-debug.log
```

My package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "webdev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node.js. My npm version is 5.6.0. This happens with every package I've tried to install. Please help, I've been trying to fix this for hours to no avail.

EDIT: I fixed it! The absolute nightmare of a program, MalwareBytes Antimalware was blocking it. I quit out of MalwareBytes and now it is working. Not the first time that program has messed up my coding.

Answer (score 0):

Delete package.json and package-lock.json file, use npm init and try again.

Probably directory node_modules doesnt exist in your project working directory

Comment: I deleted the package.json file (there is no package-lock.json) and used npm init and tried to install a package again and I'm getting the same errors. node_modules does exist, I tried deleting it and then running npm init and then installing a package again and still get the same errors

Comment: try: npm config set unsafe-perm true

Comment: or try `npm install lodash --no-optional`
I'm guesing

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you have npm installed locally in your working directory by running npm init. I would also try re-installing npm.

EDIT:

Remove MalwareBytes Anti-Malware.

Comment: I've ran npm init and tried re-installing npm like I said in the OP, same errors